# Java plug-in Extension Point

Tags: java, plugins, xtext

I am creating a programming language in xtext and I want:

1. I need to know which extension point I have to choose to create my own Run-As handler in the plug-in development.
   to create my handler of running the program by contributing to the Run As extension.
2. How to attach a command when the user right-click a table in the Data Source Explorer. I want to use the table tree node to generate some
   code.

But i do not know which extension points provide these functionality in Eclipse.

Thank You,
Abu

Answer (score 1):

1- [org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchGroups](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_debug_ui_launchGroups.html)

2- Not sure this is possible. Where does the data source explorer view comes from ? I am not aware of this view as stantard eclipse view. May be you can check with the plugins provider of this view

Comment: I configured the lauchGroup but it does not seem to have something like delegate to do the launching ..any advices?